# Python find number of student assessments by using pd.groupby and insert the score of each assessment

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataset that looks like this :
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6DQG.png)
I am trying to accumulate extra columns based on the number of assessments the student has completed.

For example, the first student has completed 5 assignments so we need to accumulate a table like this :
[acummulated_columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6DQG.png)

The id_assessment column is converted into A[i], based on number of len(id_assessments) of id_student and then each score is inserted to the relevant assignment.

What is the best approach tackling this ?

Comment: have a look on [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard)